# How can I read files from Zip file to memory with Java?

Tags: java, zip, unzip

I found example from SUN site (http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/), but it returns BufferedOutputStream. But I would like to get ZipEntry file as InputStream and then process next file. Is that possible? My program has no access to harddisk, so it cannot even temporarily save files.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class UnZip {
   final int BUFFER = 2048;
   public static void main (String argv[]) {
      try {
         BufferedOutputStream dest = null;
         FileInputStream fis = new 
       FileInputStream(argv[0]);
         ZipInputStream zis = new 
       ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
         ZipEntry entry;
         while((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Extracting: " +entry);
            int count;
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
            // write the files to the disk
            FileOutputStream fos = new 
          FileOutputStream(entry.getName());
            dest = new 
              BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);
            while ((count = zis.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) 
              != -1) {
               dest.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            dest.flush();
            dest.close();
         }
         zis.close();
      } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: And if you want to do something similar with nested zip files (inside of other zip files), some details on that can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75096589/2657515

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, just change the part that writes the file into something you want to do with the data.

```Java
while((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Extracting: " + entry);
    int count;
    byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER];
    String filename = entry.getName();
    System.out.println("Filename: " + filename);
    while ((count = zis.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
       // Do whatever you want with the data variable
       System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: `byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER];`  ??

Comment: @JohnSmith puth a 1024 int  there it is the number of bytes you are going to read from thee zip entry each While iteration

Comment: if one would like to convert the `data` into a String, don't forget to remove trailing empty bytes in the array! Convert it like this `new String(data).replaceAll("\u0000.*", "")`.This solution was taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857803/removing-extra-empty-characters-from-byte-array-and-converting-to-a-string)

Comment: @Jay no, you take `count` bytes out of `data` to prevent those null characters in the first place! Thanks for the edit anyway.

Comment: Right, makes sense, thanks for the clarification! So it should be `new String(data, 0, count)` which is much better :)

Answer (score 0):

This process reads the whole zip file and just dumps it to a stream, it does not read/split the individual files within the zip. Its sad that the ZIP library does not provide one with the inputstream of each individual file within the ZIP stream.