# Extracting PDF inside a Zip inside a Zip

Tags: java, zip, unzip, fileinputstream, zipinputstream

i have checked everywhere online and stackoverflow and could not find a match specific to this issue.
I am trying to extract a pdf file that is located in a zip file that is inside a zip file (nested zips).
Re-calling the method i am using to extract does not work nor does changing the whole program to accept Inputstreams instead of how i am doing it below.
The .pdf file inside the nested zip is just skipped at this stage

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //Paths
            String basePath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Scan\\";
            File lookupDir = new File(basePath + "Data\\");
            String doneFolder = basePath + "DoneUnzipping\\";       
            
            File[] directoryListing = lookupDir.listFiles();
                
            for (int i = 0; i < directoryListing.length; i++) 
            {
                if (directoryListing[i].isFile()) //there's definately a file
                {
                    //Save the current file's path
                    String pathOrigFile = directoryListing[i].getAbsolutePath();
                    Path origFileDone = Paths.get(pathOrigFile);
                    Path newFileDone = Paths.get(doneFolder + directoryListing[i].getName());
                            
                    //unzip it
                    if(directoryListing[i].getName().toUpperCase().endsWith(ZIP_EXTENSION)) //ZIP files
                    {
                        unzip(directoryListing[i].getAbsolutePath(), DESTINATION_DIRECTORY + directoryListing[i].getName());
                            
                        //move to the 'DoneUnzipping' folder
                        Files.move(origFileDone, newFileDone);                            
                        }
                    } 
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
            
    private static void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDir) 
    {        
        //buffer for read and write data to file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        
        try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath))) 
{
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipFilePath);
                ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
                
                while(ze != null)
                {
                    String fileName = ze.getName();
                    int index = fileName.lastIndexOf("/");
                    String newFileName = fileName.substring(index + 1);
                    File newFile = new File(destDir + File.separator + newFileName);
                    
                    //Zips inside zips  
                    if(fileName.toUpperCase().endsWith(ZIP_EXTENSION))
                    {                      
                        ZipInputStream innerZip = new ZipInputStream(zis);
                            
                                ZipEntry innerEntry = null;
                                while((innerEntry = innerZip.getNextEntry()) != null) 
                                {
                                    System.out.println("The file: " + fileName);
                                    if(fileName.toUpperCase().endsWith("PDF")) 
                                    {
                                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                                        int len;
                                        while ((len = innerZip.read(buffer)) > 0) 
                                        {
                                            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                                        }
                                        fos.close();
                                    }
                                }
                            

                    }
                    
                //close this ZipEntry
                zis.closeEntry(); // java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
                ze = zis.getNextEntry();                       
                
                }  
            
            //close last ZipEntry
            zis.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: `new FileInputStream(zipFilePath + File.separator + fileName)` doesn't work because an entry inside a ZIP file is not a file in any sense that the OS (and specifically its file APIs) care about, despite what Explorer or your platforms file manager tries to pretend). Instead of using another `FileInputStream` for the inner one, simply create a new `ZipInputStream` based on the outer `ZipInputStream`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @JoachimSauer I have commented out the new FileInputStream part and updated

```try(ZipInputStream innerZip = new ZipInputStream(innerfis))```

to 

```try(ZipInputStream innerZip = new ZipInputStream(fis))```

And now get the error: ```java.io.IOException: Stream Closed```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the current code and add details about the exception (specifically the full stack trace) to it as well. Putting those details in the comments make the question harder to answer for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found no way to do as my question states, and no one answered with the below (so sorry for answering my own question posted). The problem comes in when reading the path of the zip inside the zip.
What needs to happen, and what is illustrated below, is the nested zip needs to be moved to a temp folder and extracted there and removed afterwards.
So the unzip function is called as many times as there are nested zips.

I struggled a while with this one, hope it helps someone somewhere along the line..

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Unzipper
{   
    private static  String baseDir = "";
    private static  String PDF_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY = "";
    private static  String extractionLogFile = "";

private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
private static int count = 0;
private static int loggedCount = 0;
private static String ZIP_EXTENSION = "ZIP";

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    baseDir = File.separator + "Users" + File.separator + "user" + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator + "ZipFolder" + File.separator;
    PDF_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY = File.separator +"Users" + File.separator + "user" + File.separator +"Desktop" + File.separator + "ZipFolder" + File.separator + "PDFs" + File.separator;
    extractionLogFile = File.separator + "Users" + File.separator + "user" + File.separator +"Desktop" + File.separator + "ZipFolder" + File.separator + "ExtractionLogFile.txt";       
    

    try
    {
        //Paths
        File lookupDir = new File(baseDir);
        String doneFolder = PDF_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY;

        //Logger properties
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ExtractionLog");
        FileHandler fh;
        fh = new FileHandler(extractionLogFile);
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);

        //make some folders if they are not there
        makeDirIfNotExist(baseDir + "PDFs");
        makeDirIfNotExist(baseDir + File.separator + "_Temp");

        File[] directoryListing = lookupDir.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < directoryListing.length; i++)
        {
            if (directoryListing[i].isFile()) //there's definately a file
            {
                //Save the current file's path
                String pathOrigFile = directoryListing[i].getAbsolutePath();
                Path origFileDone = Paths.get(pathOrigFile);
                Path newFileDone = Paths.get(doneFolder + directoryListing[i].getName());

                //make sure directory exist
                String dirPDFdestName = directoryListing[i].getName();
                makeDirIfNotExist(PDF_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY.concat(dirPDFdestName.substring(0, dirPDFdestName.length() - 4)));

                //unzip it
                if (directoryListing[i].getName().toUpperCase().endsWith(ZIP_EXTENSION)) //ZIP files
                {
                    checkTheZip(directoryListing[i].getAbsolutePath(), PDF_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY.concat(dirPDFdestName.substring(0, dirPDFdestName.length() - 4)));
                    //move to the 'PDFs' folder
                    moveFile(origFileDone, newFileDone);
                }
            }
        }

        logger.info("Cycle completed, Processed files: " + loggedCount); // (just checking)
        loggedCount = 0;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        appendToFile(e);
    }
}

//dig into the zip file
private static void checkTheZip(String zipFilePath, String destDirName)
{
    unzip(zipFilePath, destDirName);
    loggedCount++;
}

//move the file
private static void moveFile(Path fromDest, Path toDest)
{
    File lookupDir = new File(toDest.toString());
    try
    {
        if(!lookupDir.exists())
        {
            Files.move(fromDest, toDest); //, OPTIONAL: StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {        
        appendToFile(e);
    }
}

private static File makeDirIfNotExist(String directory)
{
    File dir = new File(directory);
    if (!dir.exists())
    {
        dir.mkdir();
    }
    return new File(directory + File.separator);
}


   public static void appendToFile(Exception e) 
   {
      try 
      {
         FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(extractionLogFile, true);
         BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
         PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(out, true);
         e.printStackTrace(pWriter);
      }
      catch (Exception ie) 
      {
         throw new RuntimeException("Could not write Exception to file", ie);
      }
   }

private static void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirName)
{
    //buffer for read and write data to file
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath)))
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipFilePath);
        ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

        while (ze != null)
        {
            String fileName = ze.getName();
            int index = fileName.lastIndexOf(File.separator);
            String newFileName = fileName.substring(index + 1);
            File newFile = new File(destDirName + File.separator + newFileName);

            //PDFs
            if (fileName.toUpperCase().endsWith("PDF"))
            {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                int len;
                while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0)
                {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                fos.close();

            }

            //Zips inside zips  
            if (fileName.toUpperCase().endsWith(ZIP_EXTENSION))
            {
                Path newFileDone = Paths.get(baseDir + "_Temp");
                Path origFileDone = Paths.get(destDirName + File.separator);
                newFile = new File(baseDir + "_Temp" + File.separator + newFileName);
                
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                int len;
                while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0)
                {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                fos.close();

                //move the zip out of the folder to a temp folder then
                moveFile(origFileDone, newFileDone);
                
                //search the temp folder for entries and handle the .zip file from there
                checkTheZip(baseDir + "_Temp" + File.separator + fileName, destDirName);
                
                //remove the Temp_ folders contents
                Files.walk(Paths.get(baseDir + "_Temp" + File.separator))
                        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                        .map(Path::toFile)
                        .forEach(File::delete);

            }

            //close this ZipEntry
            zis.closeEntry();
            ze = zis.getNextEntry();
        }

        //close last ZipEntry
        zis.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        appendToFile(e);
    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is not as obvious as it seems. Despite writing a few zip utilities myself some time ago, getting zip entries from inside another zip file only seems obvious in retrospect
(and I also got the `java.io.IOException: Stream Closed` on my first attempt).

The Java classes for `ZipFile` and `ZipInputStream` really direct your thinking into using the file system, but it is not required.

The functions below will scan a parent-level zip file, and continue scanning until it finds an entry with a specified name. (Nearly) everything is done in-memory.

Naturally, this can be modified to use different search criteria, find multiple file types, etc. and take different actions, but this at least demonstrates the basic technique in question -- zip files inside of zip files -- no guarantees on other aspects of the code, and someone more savvy could most likely improve the style.

```java
final static String ZIP_EXTENSION = ".zip";

public static byte[] getOnePDF() throws IOException
{
    final File source = new File("/path/to/MegaData.zip");
    final String nameToFind = "FindThisFile.pdf";

    final ByteArrayOutputStream mem = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try (final ZipInputStream in = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source))))
    {
        digIntoContents(in, nameToFind, mem);
    }

    // Save to disk, if you want
    // copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toByteArray()), new FileOutputStream(new File("/path/to/output.pdf")));

    // Otherwise, just return the binary data
    return mem.toByteArray();
}

private static void digIntoContents(final ZipInputStream in, final String nameToFind, final ByteArrayOutputStream mem) throws IOException
{
    ZipEntry entry;
    while (null != (entry = in.getNextEntry()))
    {
        final String name = entry.getName();

        // Found the file we are looking for
        if (name.equals(nameToFind))
        {
            copy(in, mem);
            return;
        }

        // Found another zip file
        if (name.toUpperCase().endsWith(ZIP_EXTENSION.toUpperCase()))
        {
            digIntoContents(new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(getZipEntryFromMemory(in))), nameToFind, mem);
        }
    }
}

private static byte[] getZipEntryFromMemory(final ZipInputStream in) throws IOException
{
    final ByteArrayOutputStream mem = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    copy(in, mem);
    return mem.toByteArray();
}

// General purpose, reusable, utility function
// OK for binary data (bad for non-ASCII text, use Reader/Writer instead)
public static void copy(final InputStream from, final OutputStream to) throws IOException
{
    final int bufferSize = 4096;

    final byte[] buf = new byte[bufferSize];
    int len;
    while (0 < (len = from.read(buf)))
    {
        to.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    to.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line that causes your problem looks to be auto-close block you have created when reading the inner zip:

```
try(ZipInputStream innerZip = new ZipInputStream(fis)) {
   ...
}
```

Several likely issues: firstly it is reading the wrong stream - `fis` not the existing `zis`.

Secondly, you shouldn't use try-with-resources for auto-close on `innerZip` as this implicitly calls `innerZip.close()` when exiting the block. If you view the source code of `ZipInputStream` via a good IDE you should see (eventually) that `ZipInputStream extends InflaterInputStream` which itself `extends FilterInputStream`. A call to `innerZip.close()` will close the underlying outer stream `zis` (`fis` in your case) hence stream is closed when you resume the next entry of the outer zip.

Therefore remove the `try()` block and add use of `zis`:

```
ZipInputStream innerZip = new ZipInputStream(zis);
```

Use try-catch block only for the outermost file handling:

```
try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath))) {
    ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
    ...
}
```

Thirdly, you appear to be copying the wrong stream when extracting a PDF - use `innerZip` not outer `zis`. The code will never extract PDF as these 2 lines can never be true at the same time because a file ending ZIP will never end PDF too:

```
if(fileName.toUpperCase().endsWith(ZIP_EXTENSION)) {                      
    ...
    // You want innerEntry.getName() here
    if(fileName.toUpperCase().endsWith("PDF"))
```

You should be able to switch to one line `Files.copy` and make use of the PDF filename not zip filename:

```
if(innerEntry.getName().toUpperCase().endsWith("PDF")) {
    Path newFile = Paths.get(destDir + '-'+innerEntry.getName().replace("/", "-"));
    System.out.println("Files.copy to " + newFile);
    Files.copy(innerZip, newFile);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips & answer @DuncG i appreciate! However, your answer does clear up the error, but now the inner zip does not extract the pdf. It is just an empty folder. The inner zip seems to be skipped completely.

Comment: I added another problem above. Get a good IDE:  add useful logging messages showing what each step is doing, fix the warnings such as unused variables, step through in a debugger - it will save you a lot of wasted time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks how to use java (by implication in windows) to extract a pdf from a zip inside another outer zip.

In many systems **including windows** it is a single line command that will depend on the location of source and target folders, however using the shortest example of current downloads folder it would be in a shell as simple as

`tar -xf "german (2).zip" && tar -xf "german.zip" && german.pdf`

to shell the command in windows see
[How do I execute Windows commands in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452964/how-do-i-execute-windows-commands-in-java)

The default pdf viewer can open the result so Windows Edge or in my case SumatraPDF

[image]

There is generally no point in putting a pdf inside a zip because it cannot be run in there. So single nesting would be advisable if needed for download transportation.

There is no need to add a password to the zip because PDF uses its own password for opening. Thus unwise to add two levels of complexity. Keep it simple.

If you have multiple zips nested inside multiple zips with multiple pdfs in each then you have to be more specific by filtering names. However avoid that extra onion skin where possible.

**`\Downloads>tar -xf "german (2).zip" "both.zip" && tar -xf "both.zip" "English language.pdf"`**

You could complicate that by run in a memory or temp folder but it is reliable and simple to use the native file system so consider without Java its fastest to run

```
CD /D "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Scan/DoneUnzipping" && for  %f in (..\Data\*.zip) do  tar -xf "%f" "*.zip" && for  %f in (*.zip) do  tar -xf "%f" "*.pdf" && del "*.zip"
```

This will extract all inner zips into working folder then extract all PDFs and remove all the essential temporary zips. The source double zips will not be deleted simply touched.